# Qual o equivalente ao 'explode' de PHP em Python?

Tags: php, python, string

Em PHP, se eu quero dividir uma string em várias partes baseado num delimitador, eu uso `explode`.

Como posso fazer o mesmo em Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` é o equivalente ao `explode` de PHP, que é um método de `string`. Na verdade quase todas as linguagens em que essa funcionalidade existe é chamada de `split`, sendo o PHP o unico(ou quase) que lhe deu um nome diferente(pelos seus motivos eu sei).

O `split` permite especificar dois parâmetros:

- `sep` - separador
- `maxsplit` - máximo de divisões a serem feitas

Algo como:

```
str.split(separador, divisoes)
```

O normal é não indicar o numero de divisões e apenas o separador, assim:

```
>>> str = 'um,dois,tres,quatro,cinco'
>>> str.split(',')
['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco']
```

Neste exemplo foi feita a separação por `,`.

Quando indica o `maxsplit`, apenas divide tantas vezes quanto o numero indicado:

```
>>> str = 'um,dois,tres,quatro,cinco'
>>> str.split(',', 2)
['um', 'dois', 'tres,quatro,cinco']
```

Agora foram feitas apenas 2 divisões, deixando assim 3 elementos.

Também pode não indicar o separador, que lhe vai separar por espaço, que é o caso mais comum. Isto simplifica bastante no dia a dia pois é o mais normal de se utilizar como separador:

```
>>> str = 'um dois tres quatro cinco'
>>> str.split()
['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco']
```

Sempre que tiver dúvidas deve consultar a [documentação da função](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split).

Answer (score 2):

Usando o próprio exemplo do `explode` da documentação do PHP, você simplesmente precisaria fazer

```
pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6"
pizza.split(' ')
['piece1', 'piece2', 'piece3', 'piece4', 'piece5', 'piece6']
```

Não há necessidade de importar string.